# Issue with the Like operator on my custom field

Tags: content-search, solr

My field configuration on Sitecore:

`<field fieldName="unifiedtitle" storageType="yes" indexType="tokenized" returnType="string">Project.Foundation.Indexing.ComputedFields.UnifiedTitleComputedField, Project.Foundation.Indexing</field>`

Basically I'm facing the following situation when querying against my Solr index:

**This is returning the expected result**

`keywordsFilter.Or(item => item.UnifiedTitle.Like("The Bentley Moose Jaw"))`

or

`keywordsFilter.Or(item => item.Content.Like("Bentley Moose"))`

And as you can see here, this is the value of the `unifiedtitle` field on Solr:

[image]

**But this is not returning any result**

`keywordsFilter.Or(item => item.UnifiedTitle.Like("Bentley Moose"))`

It looks like the `Like` operator doesn't have the same behavior when I use the `UnifiedTitle` field. Even weirder, if I use the **exact value of this field** as a filter, than it works as I showed above.

Any suggestion would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try "Contains"?

Comment: Yes I did, same result...

Comment: Can you also add details of your computed index configuration?

Comment: Sure, there it is.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to fix this.

It looks like that a `returnType="string"` field can't be tokenized.

After **changing the returnType to "text"** everything is working as expected:

`<field fieldName="unifiedtitle" storageType="yes" indexType="tokenized" returnType="text">Project.Foundation.Indexing.ComputedFields.UnifiedTitleComputedField, Project.Foundation.Indexing</field>`

Comment: This is what I was thinking.... String (UTF-8 encoded string or Unicode). Strings are intended for small fields and are not tokenized or analyzed in any way. They have a hard limit of slightly less than 32K. You should use text or for multi values textcollection for tokenized